# Defining sweet alert in a service and Inject

Tags: typescript, sweetalert

Using sweet alert for alert messages in angularJS2/typescript. Since its used in more than one place in application this code is being repeated in many place.

created a service

```
@Injectable()
export class AlertMessageService {



    constructor(private http: Http) {

     }

   public deleteMessage(){
    return swal({
      title: 'Are you sure?',
      text: "Delete the selected record(s)?",
      type: 'warning',
      showCancelButton: true,
      confirmButtonColor: '#66c378',
      cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
      confirmButtonText: 'Yes'
    })
    }
```

try to use that in the component like this, which is not working.

```
  this.alertMessageService.deleteMessage.then(() => {
      if (ind !== -1 && ind != undefined) {
        this.attachments.splice(ind, 1);
      }
      /* let headers = new Headers();
        this.http.delete(AppUtils.INCIDENT_ATTACHMENT_URI+"/? path" + "=" + item.filePath,  {})
              .map(response => response.json().result)
              .catch(this.handleError);*/
    });
  }
```

Is there any way that we define it in service different types of alert types and inject it, How ?

Comment: Not really clear what you're asking. You don't know how to define a service? Or how to inject it? Have you looked at the angular tutorial?

Comment: Talking specifically related to sweet alert messages.

Comment: I don't see how that's different from any other service.

Comment: 1) Have you injected your service correctly? 2) Are you providing your service correctly (i.e. listed it in your module or component's `providers`)?

Comment: yes, Error not related to that. This is the error  [ts] Property 'then' does not exist on type '() => any'.

Comment: So what does that `swal()` function return? A `Promise`? If so, declare your service method to return `Promise<any>`.

Answer (score 0):

sweetalert.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import swal from 'sweetalert2';
@Injectable()
export class SweetAlertService {
constructor() { }
public warningAlert(textLine, isShowCancel?) {
return swal({
  title: textLine || 'Are you sure?',
  type: 'warning',
  showCancelButton: isShowCancel,
  cancelButtonText: 'No',
  confirmButtonText: isShowCancel ? 'Yes' : 'Ok',
  reverseButtons: true,
  allowOutsideClick: false
});
}
}
```

In component.ts

```
constructor(public sweetAlertService: SweetAlertService){}
const popupResponse =  this.sweetAlertService.warningAlert('Your meassage', true);

   if (popupResponse.value) {
   // press Yes on popup
    }
   else{// press cancel on popup}
```

In module.ts

`import 
providers: [SweetAlertService ]`